# NPM - how to deploy a project on to a real server whenever there're some updates

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, npm, single-page-application

I use the following script whenever updating final codes onto 'git master' on a real server.

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master

rm -rf /var/www/html/projectA/node_modules/
rm /var/www/html/projectA/package-lock.json
rm /var/www/html/projectA/public/js/react/entry.js // This is SPA
rm /var/www/html/projectA/public/mix-manifest.json

npm install --save
npm run production

// the following is Apache restarting...
```

I was wondering if which deploying method is right.
There are methods like the following.

1) the example above

2) on a real server, do only

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master

npm run production
```

3) create SPA on a local or alpha server and in a real server, do only this.

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

I have tried both 1) and 2), but I have found errors later about the case of 2),
which means there were no errors on my local but later errors on a real server as updates have been conducted.

Could you let me know if there are any good ways to deploy your projects on a real server?

1) and 2) take a long time but in the case of 3), I don't know if it is common and safe. From my experience, socket.io didn't work in 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `1)` should be:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master

// node_modules is required for npm run production
// rm -rf /var/www/html/projectA/node_modules/

// package-lock.json is required to lock the package version, to make it work like your local environment
// rm /var/www/html/projectA/package-lock.json

// Usually would overwrite them when running npm run production
// rm /var/www/html/projectA/public/js/react/entry.js // This is SPA
// rm /var/www/html/projectA/public/mix-manifest.json

npm install --save
npm run production
```

It's the proper procedure to perform an update to the server.

`2)` didn't `npm install`, how can you run `npm run production`?

`3)` is one of the viable solutions too. However, some people don't like it because they don't want to store production(build) files in their `git`. As it consumes space and your team have to download them to develop even they don't need them. `Git` is for managing source code, instead of releasing.

Comment: All these cases are that node_modules have already been installed, and as you know, the server is always updated now and future. Whenever the server is updated with changed front source codes, I know I do not need to do npm install but only npm run production. But this caused some issues that occurred on a real server but not on a local server and I found out I have to remove package-lock.json and node_modules and do npm install and then npm run production whenever I update source codes. Is this not a proper way or any other ways for releasing?

Comment: You should not need to remove those files. And you should run `npm install` whenever your `package-lock.json` updates. What is your issues without removing those files?

Comment: I just wanted to release the project and so finally chose 3) for releasing adding node_modules to .gitignore. 3) was best for releasing, but found out at that time that socket.io was not working. Now I know socket.io requires node_modules as it is at a server side.